# Retrieve and Insert million records into table

Tags: java, performance, sql-server-2008, jdbc, pagination

there's column I want to retrieve and insert into another table
For example, below is first table I want to retrieve values

`Table1
Records
1 ABC Singapore
2 DEF Vietnam`

I retrieve above column value from Table1, then insert into another table as below

`Table 2
ID   Name   Country
1    ABC    Singapore
2    DEF    Vietname`

Currently, I can do with java, I first retrieve records then split the values and insert. However, I want to do it by batch or pagination for better performance when Table1 got million of records to retrieve and insert those million records into Table2.

Any pointer to show me how to use pagination in my case would be appreciated.

I"m use MSSQL 2008

Comment: Why not just use the sql script to do it ? But that considering your records format is going to be same for every record. Using sql it would be easy and efficient. You can write `Split()` function to split record and then insert query

Comment: value from Table1 is only one column value. I need to split first inside sql script and insert into table 2, don't know how to split and not very expert in sql script :(

Comment: Here is how you can write split function http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings and then incoming records are needed to insert in desired table

Comment: if i do it in sql script, it's more efficient even there r million of records?

Comment: Yes. Because DBMS are build to handle and process the big databases and large number of records.

Comment: what about choosing jdbc pagination over sql script? because the delimiter in my case is not constant : sometimes 'space', '$', 'comma'.

Comment: You can do that. But for efficiency I would still use sql. And you can define your split function to handle each type of delimiter that your records have.

Comment: I used store procedure to insert million of records and call that store procedure from my java. After I run using visualvm, the result shows me that my method which run that store procedure took over 80% cpu :(

Answer (score 1):

If you *need* to do that in code (and not in SQL which should be easier even with multiple delimiters), what you probably want to use would be batched inserts with proper batch size combined with a good fetch-size on your select:

```
    //Prepare statements first
    try(PreparedStatement select = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM SOURCE_TABLE");
            PreparedStatement insert = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO TARGET_TABLE(col1, col2, col3) VALUES (?,?,?)")) {

        //Define Parameters for SELECT
        select.setFetchDirection(ResultSet.FETCH_FORWARD);
        select.setFetchSize(10000);

        int rowCnt = 0;

        try(ResultSet rs = select.executeQuery()) {
            while(rs.next()) {
                String row = rs.getString(1);
                String[] split = row.split(" |\\$|\\*"); //However you want to do that
                //Todo: Error handling for array length

                //Todo: Type-Conversions, if target data is not a string type
                insert.setString(1, split[0]);
                insert.setString(2, split[1]);
                insert.setString(3, split[2]);
                insert.addBatch();

                //Submit insert in batches of a good size:
                if(++rowCnt % 10000 == 0) {
                    int[] success = insert.executeBatch();
                    //Todo: Check if that worked.
                }
            }
            //Handle remaining inserts
            int[] success = insert.executeBatch();
            //Todo: Check if that worked.               
        }

    } catch(SQLException e) {
        //Handle your Exceptions
    }
```

On calculating on "good" fetch and batch sizes you'll want to consider some parameters:

- Fetchsize impacts memory consumption in your client. If you have enough of that you can make it big.
- Committing an insert of millions of rows will take some time. Depending on your requirements you might want to commit the insert transaction every once in a while (every 250.000 inserts?)
- Think about your transaction isolation: Make sure auto-commit is turned off as committing each insert will make most of the batching gains go away.

Comment: hey Jan, thanks. Actually I did it in sql script. However, I will try this again. No harm to know how to use batch query with java. Thanks man